# PBKDF2 key is decrypting AES without the same salt?

Tags: encryption, aes, pbkdf2, cbc-mode

How is the following possible without saving and reusing the salt from PBKDF2?

**Here's what I'm doing to *encrypt* a file:**

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -in secret.txt -out secret.enc -a -kfile kfile.file
```

Where `secret.txt = "secret message"`, and `kfile.file = "password"`

**I then run the following to *decrypt* the just encrypted file:**

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -d -in secret.enc -out secret.decrypted -a -kfile kfile.file
```

The decrypted file results `secret.decrypted = "secret message"`

As far as I know, I would have needed the initial salt used for the PBKDF2 to derive the same key for decryption, why is this clearly not the case here?

When running `openssl aes-256-cbc -help` it states that a salt is used in the KDF by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (implicitly generated) random 8 bytes salt and the ciphertext are automatically concatenated. In addition, the ASCII encoding of `Salted__` is prepended:

`<ASCII encoding of Salted__>|<8 bytes salt>|<ciphertext>`

The `-a` option causes the result to be Base64 encoded. Because of the fixed prefix `Salted__` the data therefore always starts with `U2FsdGVkX1`.

Comment: That makes sense, the common prefix `U2FsdGVkX1` has been puzzling me. That cleared it up. Thank you. Is this common practice? Or is this just what the aes-256-cbc routine does?

Comment: @xornoz - This applies in general, i.e. also when other algorithms are used or the deprecated default key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` is used.